# How to Filter data when a selection is made in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, frameworks

This is my select ID with data fetched from the database

**HTML**

```
<select id = "mySelectID" name = "select" data-sel="select"> 
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

**JSON**

```
var jsonData = [{"id":"jmbaaaro@kaps.co.ke","passkey":null},{"id":"willson@gmail.com","passkey":"3694"},{"id":"info@llvswaterboard.go.ke","passkey":null},{"id":"rundda@athiwater.com","passkey":"5576"},{"id":"pk@.k.com","passkey":"1835"},{"id":"pkinnyanjui@kaps.co.ke","passkey":null},{"id":"wilsson@gmail.com","passkey":"3694"}{"id":"wycllif@kaps.co.ke","passkey":"2318"},{"id":"wycllif@gmail.com","passkey":"2318"},{"id":"alexx@gmail.com","passkey":"2710"},{"id":"wilsson@gmail.com","passkey":"3694"},{"id":"barbeggambo@gmail.com","passkey":"8917"},{"id":"bachu@gmail.com","passkey":"5857"}]
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    //var jsonData = JSON.parse(s);
    var select = $$('#mySelectID');
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var option = $("<option/>").attr("value",jsonData[i].id).text(jsonData[i].id);
       select.append(option);
    }   

    $("select#mySelectID").change(function(){
       var selectedmail = $("#mySelectID").val();
       var s = jsonData.filter(function (e){
       return e.id ==='3694';
    });
```

I am trying to get the value with passkey 3694. Please Assist i am new to javascript.

Comment: select.append(option);
                }   ignore this part

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45099510/edit edit your question. __Never__ add pieces of code to comments.

Comment: @Barbe Swach Gambino What do you mean "get the value with passkey?" You want to save it in `variable` while iterating or pick as selected option?

Comment: I meant filtering the passkey using the email id